# Android webView always show url in tilte

Tags: android, android-webview

I use this code to load WebView

```
web.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
    @Override
    public void onReceivedTitle(WebView view, String title) {
         getWindow().setTitle(title); //Set Activity tile to page title.
    }
});

web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return false;
    }
});
```

This code works but when the title is empty , the webview will show the url of the page in the title. How to solve it?

Comment: So, Is your problem resolved?????

Comment: In fact, when the title in html is null, the title in onReceivedTitle is not null, but the url of the webview

Comment: The same problem. Waiting for solution.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this...

```
 web.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
        @Override
        public void onReceivedTitle(WebView view, String title) {
             if(title!=null && title!="")
             getWindow().setTitle(title); //Set Activity tile to page title.
             else
             getWindow().setTitle("");
        }
    });
```

May it help !